# Will a Nikon D7100 and 35mm Nikkor lens with extension tubes work well for getting started with macro photography?

Tags: lens, macro, nikon-d7100

I have just started pursuing my hobby full time and am still in the learning phase. I have a Nikon D7100 with a Nikon AF-S DX NIKKOR 35 mm f/1.8G Lens. I would really appreciate if anyone can advise me if the 35mm would work well on the Kenko Extension tubes all fitted to the Nikon D7100 body...for starting with Macrophotography ?

At the moment, I don't want to use the reversing ring — I want to use the AF mechanism.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice. I appreciate. Agreeing to what you are saying, I also have a Tamron AF 70 - 300 mm F/4-5.6 Di LD Macro....which captures some decent shots. It is rather a heavy lens....Can i use it with the Kenko extenion tubes in the normal mode to do some macro photography as buying one more lens is not in budget at the moment. I am planning to buy the extension tubes if i can at least use any of my existing lenses either the 35mm(not recommended as it needs to be pretty close to the subject) or the Tamron lens(i hope it works).

Comment: May I request anybody out there to advise on that. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Adi. This is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum. If you have a separate question, please ask it separately. (If it is a followup to this one, a link back might be a good idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Nikon D7000 and the DX 35mm f/1.8 and the Kenko extension tubes.  Technically the answer to your question is 'yes', but practically the answer is 'no'.

The problem lies with the distance of the camera lens to the subject.  The 35mm lens makes it so that your lens is practically in contact with your subject-this will throw shadows, reduce your in-focus area to almost zero (a tiny fraction of an inch), and greatly magnify movement (yours and that of the subject.)

I prefer my 105mm macro lens with the extension tubes because it gives more breathing room between you and your subject (I like to shoot bees and wasps), and it increases the depth of the in-focus area.

Experiment with your rig, use a tripod along with a cable release, the little electronic Nikon ML-L3 release, or the camera's self-timer.  Use an off-camera flash if you have one, or off camera lighting.  Most of all take your time and have fun doing it.

Comment: The practical answer really depends on the subject matter and the lighting setup. In some situations a wide angle lens works better for certain types of macro photography, in other situations it doesn't.